# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError throwed when execute an appium based framework

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I'm getting the error in framework which works perfectly last Monday (yesterday). The code has been not changed and no updates were performed in eclipse. Today, when I tried to run tests I got the error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.(java.net.URI, java.time.Duration, java.time.Duration, org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter, java.net.Proxy, org.openqa.selenium.Credentials)'
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.(AppiumClientConfig.java:62)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumClientConfig.defaultConfig(AppiumClientConfig.java:79)
> at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:109)
> at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:92)
> at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:117)
> at common.BaseConfigs.getDriver(BaseConfigs.java:38)
> at com.netflix.XXXTests.setUp(XXXTests.java:93)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:62)
> at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:385)
> at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:321)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.invokeTestConfigurations(TestRunner.java:637)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:627)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:589)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
> at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

getDriver metod looks like:

> 

public static AndroidDriver getDriver() throws IOException{

```
    //read data from data.properties file to get device name, app package name and app activity name
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\resources\\data.properties");
    prop.load(fis);
    
    String deviceName = prop.getProperty("deviceName");
    String appPackage = prop.getProperty("appPackage");
    String appActivity = prop.getProperty("appActivity");
            
    UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
    options.setDeviceName(deviceName);
    options.setAutomationName("uiautomator2");
    options.setAppPackage(appPackage);
    options.setAppActivity(appActivity);
    options.setPlatformName("Android");
    options.disableWindowAnimation();
    options.setNewCommandTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(180));
    
    AndroidDriver driver = null;
    
    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), options);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Appium session could not be started. Please check if Appium server is running.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return driver;
}
```

I can also said that on other machine, with the same framework, everything works fine.

What I did before asking here:

- I set in pom.xml newest appium and selenium versions I found on maven
- I tried different appium and selenium configurations
- I have updated open jdk to jdk-21 and I have changed it in environmental variables
- I set in Eclipse under JRE System Library Execution environment to JavaSE-18(jdk-10-0.1.1)
- I have updated eclipse to version 2023-09 (4.29.0)

What can I do now? I'm stuck and I don't know what can I do as next. Deleting entire .m directory to download all dependencies can help with that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by using newest appium version 8.6.0, which was published the day when the problem occurred.